# How to create a gradient box in HTML using a strip (thin line) of gradient image?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the following strip of image:

[image]

I'd like to use that to create a larger box like this:

[image]

and even better, I'd like to put a text, say, "Shop here!" in the center of the created box.

How do I achieve that in HTML+CSS? Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: you can just use itbas background image for your div box and add property background-repeat: repeat-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the background property to set the `background-image` url() and the `background-repeat` repeat-x values. Then center the text with flex box:

```css
.gradient{
   background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qnum.png) repeat-x;
   /*same as*/
   /*background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qnum.png);
   background-repeat: repeat-x;*/
   height:194px;
   border-radius: 10px;

   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">Shop Here!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the use of image and recreate the same using `linear-gradient`. You can also easily change color and other properties later and it will also be responsive on height:

```css
.gradient{
   background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom,#3888fe ,transparent 80%) top,
    linear-gradient(to top,#3888fe,transparent 80%) bottom;
   background-size:100% 50%;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   height:150px;
   width:150px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   text-align:center;
   line-height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">Shop Here!</div>
```